# OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() сигнализирует о внесении изменений, но обновления данных в бд не происходит

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

В небольшом приложении бд создаю форму для изменения данных в таблице. Обработчик нажатия кнопки:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int delivery = int.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
        int order = int.Parse(this.textBox2.Text);
        string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\minedb.mdb";
        string query = "UPDATE Заказ SET [Код доставки] = @delivery WHERE [Код заказа] = @order";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        MyCommand.Connection = conn;
        MyCommand.CommandText = query;
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@delivery", OleDbType.Integer,40);
        MyCommand.Parameters["@delivery"].Value = delivery;
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@order", OleDbType.Integer,40);
        MyCommand.Parameters["@order"].Value = order;
        int success = MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (success != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(success), "Изменение записи");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось внести изменения", "Изменение записи");
        conn.Close();
    }
```

*да-да, магическая кнопка*

ExecuteNonQuery весело рапортует о внесении изменений, success равен одному или более, но открывая БД в Access обнаруживаю, что ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операторы UPDATE, INSERT и DELETE возвращают количество строк, которые были обработаны с их помощью.Для всех прочих типов операторов возвращаемым значением является -1.В случае отката также возвращается значение -1.

Comment: В моём случае используется оператор UPDATE, возвращающий единицу, то есть изменения должны быть применены.

Comment: Проблема скорее всего в следующем:
базу ты создал в студии, поэтому она лежит в папке с проектом, при компиляции она каждый раз копируется в папку с готовой программой и перетирает существующую базу, с которой работает непосредственно программа

Варианты решения: настроить доступ к БД независимо от расположения приложения или отключить копирование БД из папки проекта при каждом построении

Comment: База данных затирается, да, но копнув глубже я выяснил, что проблема еще и в этом запросе - "UPDATE Заказ SET [Код доставки] = @delivery WHERE [Код заказа] = @order". Если вместо переменных использовать просточисла, то изменения вносятся успешно (хотя и затираются при повторном запуске проги).

Comment: Тут нужно при отладке посмотреть какую SQL строку передают в БД. Я вообще ее копирую и пробую выполнить непосредственно в БД

Comment: насколько я понял строка передаётся как есть http://i73.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0220/76/4734d12c522d9f25c6e35220b9568376.png

Comment: Вопрос не в том как передается, а в том, что выполняя запрос в БД можно определить где ошибка. Так например MS SQL Managment studio позволяет дебажить SQL запросы, в Access тоже можно выполнить запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка была из-за невнимательности. А как предотвратить копирование БД?

Comment: кликаешь правой кнопкой мыши по файлу БД в обозревателе решения и выбираешь Свойства->Copy to Output Direcory